# How to change the series name using django-chartit?

Tags: python, django

I just got crazy about changing the series name using django-chartit. I have google the solutions but i cannot find it.

Here's my views.py. I even didn't know which place should i add the series' name attribute. So i just guess that might should be placed in the `series_option` . But as you have guessed, nothing has changed. And the series' name still remained "click time"

```
def userdata_chart_view(request):

    userdata = \
        DataPool(
            series=
            [{'options': {
                'source': User_Data.objects.filter(user=request.user.username)},
                'terms': [
                    'user',
                    'word',
                    'click_times']}
            ])

    cht = Chart(
        datasource= userdata,
        series_options =
            [{'options':{
                'type': 'column',
                'stacking': False},
            'terms':{
                'word': ['click_times']
                    },
            'name': '搜索次数',
            }],
        chart_options=
        {
         'title': {'text': '搜索频率'},
         'xAxis': {'title': {'text': '词条'}},
         'yAxis': {'title': {'text': '频率'}},

         }
    )

    content1 = {'user_data_chart': cht}
    return render(request, 'yigu/charts.html', content1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same difficulty, and found a way that I share with you : based on [this example](http://chartit.shutupandship.com/demo/pivot/simple/) from the chartit demo, it looks that you can simply rename a field during the DataPool creation. I used the syntax from the example (though based on a PivotDataPool, but it looks ok for any DataPool...) by changing the 'terms' value from a list to a dictionnary. In this dictionnary keys are the customized names used in the charts objects, and values are the original field names.

For your example, it might look like this :

```
userdata = \
    DataPool(
        series=
        [{'options': {
            'source': User_Data.objects.filter(user=request.user.username)},
            'terms': {
                'user': 'user',
                'word': 'word',
                '<your customized name>': 'click_times'}}
        ])

cht = Chart(
    datasource= userdata,
    series_options =
        [{'options':{
            'type': 'column',
            'stacking': False},
        'terms':{
            'word': ['<your customized name>']
                },
        ...
```

I hope this works for you, I'll be happy to know if there are more conventional ways to do it...

Answer (score 0):

PolRaguénès' answer pointed me in the right direction. It was just the bracketing in the DataPool definition for terms that had to be fixed:

```js
userdata = \
    DataPool(
        series=
        [{'options': {
            'source': User_Data.objects.filter(user=request.user.username)},
            'terms': [
                'user': 'user',
                'word': 'word',
                {'<your customized name>': 'click_times'}]}
        ])
```